# How am I supposed to ask questions when I'm trying to discern evolution or conservation of a rule or intent across D&D editions?

Tags: discussion

Apparently, asking for individual edition answers in the [dungeons-and-dragons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons) tag is too broad; is the proper procedure for such cross-edition questions to ask one question per edition I'm interested in, or is there something *else* I should be doing with this?

Comment: Asking about the evolution of a rule *is* typically done with [tag:dungeons-and-dragons], but that doesn’t mean that a given question isn’t still too broad. But that depends on the question. Can you link the question for which this became “apparent” to you?

Comment: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59415/what-is-the-prone-state-for-a-winged-flying-create-in-dd-supposed-to-correspond

Answer (score 5):

Tagging wise you're asking the question correctly, using either dungeons-and-dragons as a spanning tag if you're talking about comparison across all/a lot of editions, and 2-3 specific ones if you're doing a more limited comparison.  The tagging isn't what's wrong with that question.

"I want comparison of 5 editions" should not garner 5 answers each of which just talk about one edition. No answer is then correct and helpful unto itself. If you want a comparison of X over Y, you need to wait for someone that understands X over Y to answer. That's the price of wanting a big expansive answer (well, and the price of "too broad" which it can bump up against).

Also consider what problem you're trying to solve.  "Curiosity" isn't much of a real problem and often people will vote that way. Remember on a SE you are asking people to do work to help you. Just asking them to "write a dissertation because it amuses me" is less well received, and that's just life.